# Stack trace error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having the error message:I can`t figure out what is wrong.  Can someone help me please.  Thanks.

> > Stack Trace:
>
> [NotSupportedException: Collection is
>   read-only.]
>   System.SZArrayHelper.Clear() +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.CollectionHelpers.ReplaceCollectionImpl(ICollection`1
>   collection, IEnumerable newContents)
>   +125
>
> ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

My code is:
Model:

```
 namespace TestArrays.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public CategoriesRow[] Categories { get; set; }
        public Person()
        {

            Categories = new CategoriesRow[1];
            Categories[0] = new CategoriesRow();
            Categories[0].Name = "Bug";
            Categories[0].ID = "0";
        }
    }

    public class CategoriesRow
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String ID { get; set; }
    }

}
```

---

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Person());
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Person/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

---

Views

```
    <form id="Form" action="<%=Url.Action("Create",new{Action="Create"}) %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="categoriessection" >
            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <ul class= "list"  id="categoryList">
            <%if (Model.Categories!=null) {%> 
            <%int count = 0; %>
                <%foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
                 {%>
                 <%if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category.Name))                   
                   {%>
                    <li><input type="hidden" name="Categories.Index" value="<%=count%>" />
                        <input type="text" value="<%=category.Name%>"  name="Categories[<%=count%>].Name" style="width:280px"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<%=category.ID%>"  name="Categories[<%=count++%>].ID" style="width:280px"/>
                        <input type="button" value = "Delete"/>
                    </li>
                    <%}
                     %>
                 <%} %>
             <%} %>            
                <li> <input type="hidden" name="Categories.Index" value="value0" />
                 <input type="text" value=""  name="Categories[value0].Name" style="width:280px"/>
                  <input type="hidden" value=""  name="Categories[value0].ID" style="width:280px"/>
                     <input type="button"  value= "Add" />
                </li>
             </ul>
        </div>

         <div>
         <input  type ="submit" value="Save" id="save" /> 
         </div>
         </form>
```

Comment: I suspect the problem pertains to what is returned from `<%foreach (var category in Model.Categories)`.  More precisely, the 'Model.Categories' part, for which your code snippet does not show a definition.  Perhaps clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use lists instead of vectors in models:

```
public List<CategoriesRow> Categories { get; set; }
```